# NetGroupEnum() when offline

Tags: c++, winapi, active-directory

I want to get the groups the local machine belongs to in the domain.
The function `NetGroupEnum()` returns these groups, but **only** when the computer is online.

The problem is what do I do when I am **offline**?

I know the information is available because I can find it using various tools, but I don't know how they're doing it.

I've been looking for quite some time, doesn't anyone know how?

**Important:** I don't want to use WMI.

Also, a solution in C# is also okay, but WINAPI is much more preferable.

EDIT: To be more specific, I am trying to find out which security groups the local machine belongs to. I can see it using gpresult.exe even when I am offline.

Comment: The NetGroupEnum() function returns all groups, not those groups that a particular user or computer belongs to.  Which are you trying to do?  Also, you say you can find this information while offline "using various tools" but what is an example of a tool that does this?

Comment: @HarryJohnston - updated my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want [NetQueryDisplayInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370610.aspx) with level = 3 to retrieve [group information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370682.aspx).

This will retrieve locally-cached information when possible, so they can work when the computer is offline (and even when online, typically give faster response that `NetGroupEnum` anyway).

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to answer. For some reason this function always returns "None" (!?!?).
My computer belongs to a global security group (checked with gpresult).